# create triangular effect on view in titanium

Tags: javascript, android, ios, uiscrollview, titanium

How can I create this triangular effect on a view and the effect on the scrollview like the image describes?

I know how to create the scroll and populate it and how to create my view bot don't know how to create this effect in titanium javascript.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Imagine the view we want to hide with triangular effect is the green view,

so create a view yellow with rotation = 15° parent of green View, set to the green view a rotation = -15°,left = 0 and fix dimension width, height

inset the yellow view in your window with top = -Y, left = -X, calculate the X,Y to center the green view in screen

now you can have the triangular effect on changing the width of the yellow view

Comment: I have tested the code and it worked. thanks.But I'm having some problems. Imagine I have a scroll view inside my green view. when I add labels and views to my scroll and scroll it my labels and views disappear. this happens in android